# jQuery Calendar with custom date ranges

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have had a search, and some answers do hit on my problem, but aren't quite close enough.

I am putting together a booking system, and have a range of "tariffs" in a MySQL db.

All of these tariffs have a date range (and other values such as price per night etc, which are not relevant to this particular problem).

Using jQuery.datePicker I would like to know if there is a way I can allow only dates within the date range from the MySQL db to be selected, and any dates that aren't included in those ranges, are blanked out/unselectable.

The table "tariff" is laid out as follows :

```
id        date_from        date_to        color       price       min
1         2012/02/01       2012/03/15     red         10          2
2         2012/03/16       2013/04/10     green       7           0
2         2012/05/16       2013/06/10     green       7           0
```

So the only dates that should be selectable are from 1st Feb 2012 to 10th April 2012 and 16th May 2012 to 10June 2012, with the rest blanked out. The color, price and min value are irrelevant to this problem.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

After further searching I ended up face palming myself as I found the solution on here. For anybody else who stumbles upon my question and needs the solution, go here:

[jQuery ui: multiple ranges for date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502073/jquiery-ui-multiple-ranges-for-date-picker)

Thanks to those that answered!

Comment: I would suggest to store those date ranges into an array. Then, when the user clicks a date, compare if it is allowed or not ($.inArray...) and show a message. If it's not allowed, show a message and keep the datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery datepicker has "minDate" and "maxDate" parameters.

```
$(selector).datepicker({
    'minDate': new Date(2012, 2, 1),
    'maxDate': new Date(2012, 3, 15)
});
```

or in your php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#date").datepicker({
        'dateFormat': 'm/d/yy',
        'minDate': new Date(<?php echo $minDate->format('Y, m, d'); ?>),
        'maxDate': new Date(<?php echo $maxDate->format('Y, m, d'); ?>)
    });
});
</script>
```