# Specifying a Winter Date Range For Jquery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the jquery UI datepicker for a ski holiday search tool. As this will be used only for winter holidays in Europe, I want to restrict the months shown to Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar and Apr. Does anyone know if there is a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jqueryUI docs:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

You only have to specify when you want your min and max dates:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});

//Or also use a setter

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2012, 1 - 1, 1) );
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2013, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

In setter, dates are Date( Year, month, day ), and in month you have to substract 1.

Comment: thanks for that - I was over complicating it in my mind when the solution was actually very simple! Out of interest, would it be possible to show the winter months for two years so Dec-Apr 12/13 and then Dec-Apr 13/14?

Comment: Yes, it is, :D, check this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502073/jquiery-ui-multiple-ranges-for-date-picker

Answer (score 0):

Set mindate and maxdate as follows:

```
$('#date').datepicker('option', { minValue: new Date(startDate),
                                  maxValue: new Date(endDate) });
```

Comment: I like your way of writting the options, XD, much better than mine!