# jquery datepicker multiple min max dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, range

I am having a bit of trouble with jQuery datepicker. I need multiple ranges for date selection. For example user should be able to select a range between(d-m-y) 1/8/2015 and 5/8/2015. But also a range between: 16/8/2015 to 20/8/2015 (in the same calendar). The dates that do not match those ranges should be inactive. I ended up trying following code but with no success:

```
    $(function() {    
    var ds = array('1-8-2015', '16-8-2015'),
        de = array('5-8-2015', '20-8-2015');

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShow: function() {
            return {
                dateFormat: 'd-m-yy',
                minDate: ds,                
                maxDate: de,

            }
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle example:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/1029/)

Any ideas? 
Regards, Simon

Comment: Check out this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709320/jquery-ui-datepicker-enable-only-specific-days-in-array

Comment: Thanks for your ultra fast response. However my question is a bit different :)

Answer (score 2):

Well yes.. You can do it.. You can make use of `beforeShowDay` option of `datepicker` as below:

```
var d1s = new Date(2010, 8, 1),
    d1e = new Date(2010, 8, 5),
    d2s = new Date(2010, 8, 16),
    d2e = new Date(2010, 8, 20);
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      return [(date >= d1s && date <= d1e || date >= d2s && date <= d2e), ''];
    },
    minDate: d1s,
    maxDate: d2e
  });
});​
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3502183/2065039)**

Comment: Ain't it possible without having to define the variable number? What I forgot to mention was that the dates is dynamically generated via PHP so I don't know how many dates there is. That's why a array would be preferable if possible :)

Comment: Let me try my best to meet your requirement.. :)

Comment: Example: daystart: ['1-8-2015', '15-8-2015'], dayend ['5-8-2015', '20-8-2015'] :)

Comment: Am sorry to say buddy.. But there isn't any such option in jquery datepicker to loop array in `beforeShowDay` which itself will form a loop.. There might be some plugins available in google for this particular requirement and I tried my best to achieve in all possible ways but did not find any way to pass array incrementally..

Comment: So there is no way to set multiple ranges? That sounds weird :/

Comment: There are ways but not for the requirement you have.. As I said `beforeShowDay` will itself loop for a number of days current displaying month has and if you try to loop same array inside one more loop that will sound weird.. That is why I said you might get some good plugins to achieve this if you google..